# javascript cookie, Ember

Tags: javascript, cookies, ember.js

I want to put a user input into a cookie to save the value for later display. It seems I can write into the cookie, but not able to get the value back. I have this simple test set up:

```
            var test = "TEST"; 
            document.cookie = "usr=TEST;";
            $.cookie("usr", test); 
            Ember.$.cookie('usr', test); 
            console.log("COOKIE", $.cookie("usr"), Ember.$.cookie('usr'), "cookie.length=", document.cookie.length);
```

Which results to the output "COOKIE undefined undefined cookie.length=0". 
I don't see why I don't get my value out, seems like a simple thing. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem - needed to run the project from localhost to test.

Comment: I recommend you delete this question. Seems super localized to your project and the the solution isn't related to the anticipated problem.